# Is automatic failover built into Redis 2.8?

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I am planning on adding Redis to our application as a session and cache store.  I have been looking at how to make Redis highly available on an on-premise hosted solution.

The standard approach appears to be to set up Redis as a 3 node replica and use Sentinel for the monitoring and automatic failover.

Redis 2.8 introduces Redis cluster.  Does that mean it brings in automatic failover etc and we no longer need to use Sentinel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Cluster and Failover are different scenarios. Also Cluster is in 3.0, not 2.8.

The standard (and minimum) setup for HA is a master and one slave (aka "a pod"), with a *separate* set of three nodes which run Sentinel and monitor the pod.

This is to ensure failover of the server. However, either your client library has to support using Sentinel to discover master and reconnect on failure, you implement it in your code, or you set up a TCP load balancer and a sentinel monitoring daemon to update your load balancer configuration when a failover occurs at which point the client code doesn't know or care about sentinel.

Cluster isn't there to provide HA, it is there for server-side sharding of data. For Cluster you're looking at 6-7 nodes minimum (3 master, 3 slave, 1 spare) as well as Cluster support in the client and restrictions about commands and Lua script which need to access multiple keys.